# Problem with function which fetches from CoreData (using .fetchOffset & .fetchLimit)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I’m trying to fetch objects from Core Data using .fetchOffset & .fetchLimit. I wrote the func, which fetches the data with some preset parameters in order to change it dynamically, but after executing it I get an error «Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1d5291f08)» with the empty console.
Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData


struct ContentView: View {

    @State var offset = 0
    @State var limit = 10

    func getFlights(offset: Int, limit: Int) -> FetchRequest<Flight> {
        var fetchRequest : FetchRequest<Flight>

        let request: NSFetchRequest<Flight> = Flight.fetchRequest()
        request.fetchOffset = offset
        request.fetchLimit = limit
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Flight.date, ascending: false)]
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Flight>(fetchRequest: request)

        return fetchRequest
    }


    var body: some View {
        Text("Tap")
            .onTapGesture {
                print(self.getFlights(offset: 0, limit: 10).wrappedValue.count)  // error occurs here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where does the error occur? Maybe to do with the print. Try this print(String(self.getFlights(offset: 0, limit: 10).wrappedValue.count))

Comment: Error occurs in a print line. Unfortunately your solution does not work. Interesting thing is when I initialize the fetch request in the the View it works perfectly fine with the exactly the same code, but it stars to crash when being wrapped in a func.